# Changing :active style at each click

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a button as shown here http://jsfiddle.net/9epgs999/ Code

```
button:active{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

At :active state the button changes its background color from green to yellow. What i am trying to do is to change the background-color to blue when it is at :active state on second time (second click) and at the third click some other color is there a way to do this using css only

Comment: No, I don't think it would be possible because CSS wouldn't have a way to track the no. of clicks. It would require JS.

Comment: @Harry I am new at the selectors i was wondering something like nth child or something

Comment: you can use something like focus http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/9epgs999/1/ or jquery will be the best option

Comment: Nothing wrong in asking mate. So don't worry :)

Comment: isn't there any way like using the ::after or something cause if this works it's gonna be a lot of help to me

Comment: It's actually possible to do in CSS only, just a little tricky.

Comment: @dfsq I don't mind can you show it

Comment: This is a but clumsy, but you get the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/9epgs999/2/

Comment: @NicoO Thank you it is really helpful. I asked for css because i am planning on making an onclick function using css

Comment: @Akshay It would involve several checkboxes, general sibling selectors, :checked pseudo class, and everything wrapped into one more container. Yes, pretty verbose.

Comment: @dfsq ok its fine for me

Comment: @dfsq: By any chance do you mean absolute positioning of buttons on top of each other and then hide or display based on which check-box is selected?

Comment: @Harry Yeah i really didn't thought about that

Comment: I think it will not possible with plain css only. you should use javascript, jquery solution for the same.

Comment: @Akshay See the demo of my idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my idea. As you see it's pretty verbose, but you can technically make it work with only CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" class="check yellow" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check blue" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="check red" />
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.btn-wrap {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.btn-wrap .check {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
.btn-wrap .check:checked {
    z-index: -1;
}

.btn-wrap button {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green;
}

.btn-wrap .red:active ~ button {
    background-color: white;
}
.btn-wrap .red:checked ~ button:active {
    background-color: red;
}

.btn-wrap .blue:active ~ button {
    background-color: red;
}
.btn-wrap .blue:checked ~ button:active {
    background-color: blue;
}

.btn-wrap .yellow:active ~ button {
    background-color: blue;
}
.btn-wrap .yellow:checked ~ button:active {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9epgs999/3/

The idea is pretty simple. There are not many options how to store state in CSS. One of them is using checkboxe's `:checked` pseudo class with sibling selectors.

Even though it can be done in CSS, however I would better go with just a few lines of javascript code.

Comment: That is brilliant. Sort of expected that after your first explanation in comments. And I also fully agree with that last line. It is never good to over complicate the markup unnecessarily.

Comment: @Harry And here is what i have done with your idea http://jsfiddle.net/9epgs999/4/

Comment: @Harry True, it's not semantical at all, and effect is not worth effort. But still funny that it's possible.

Comment: Thanks again i was able to do a lot with your answer. Thanks for the effort